# How to receive organization data from LinkedIn API?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm struggling with LinkedIn API and will appreciate any help.

What I need is to get latest articles that were posted or shared by my organization to than put them on our website.

What I have so far:

- created an app;
- app is assigned (Verified) to a company page (same page that I'm trying to get from API)
- in app products: added "Share on LinkedIn" and "Sign In with LinkedIn". Still have "Marketing Developer Platform" product marked as "Review in progress".
- In OAuth 2.0 scopes we have:

  - r_emailaddress (Use the primary email address associated with your LinkedIn account)
  - r_liteprofile (Use your name and photo)
  - w_member_social (Create, modify, and delete posts, comments, and reactions on your behalf)
- Using PHP managed to get authentication code and exchange it for access code.

Than I use this function to make API calls:

```
function request_api( $url, $vars, $type = "POST", $headers = [] ){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    if ( $type == "POST" ) {
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $vars ) );
    }
    if ( $headers ) {
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $server_output = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    return $server_output;
}
```

When I make call to `request_api( "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", [], "GET", $headers );` I get normal response - json encoded info (name, image etc.)

But requests to `/organization` fail with `403` error.
I tried `request_api( "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=my_organization_vanity_name", [], "GET", $headers );` and it return `{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-vanityName /organizations","status":403}`.

I'm not the admin in `my_organization_vanity_name` so I don't know the organization id and according to docs I can't request from `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/my_organization_id`

I'd like to know if I for sure will get the company data with authenticated admin user using the code above.

And if so, how can I obtain the articles that were posted/shared on organization page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the "rw_organization_admin" scope as well.

For this you need to request the "Marketing Developer Platform" product.

I checked this by using Postman.

Comment: Thank you! This is not relevant anymore but maybe will be useful in future